# user id change automatically to username using htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

hi  im using htaccess to change `profile.php?u=<username>` to mywebsite/username  it works perfectly when i use it in my links but i want it to change automatically when someone write `profile.php?id=<uid>`

for example in facebook when you write "www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=4" it change to "www.facebook.com/zuck"

my htaccess code

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ profile.php?u=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ profile.php?u=$1`

what can i add to it ? please help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing, since you most certainly don't have a list available to Apache which contains the mapping of your user IDs to their respective user names. Facebook performs the redirect with their PHP application by querying their database for the ID and redirecting you to the respective new URL containing the user's name which was retrieved from their database. Such a PHP script could look like:

```
<?php

$options = array("options" => array("min_range" => 1));
if (($id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "id", FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, $options)) {
    $user = new User($id);
    header("Location http://example.com/{$user->name}", true, 303);
    exit();
}
```

Comment: hi thanks alot for the reply  you gave me an idea  i used `if(isset($_GET["id"])){
 header("location: $u");
    exit(); 
}` and it worked great  but is there any vulnerability , sorry im still new in this

Comment: There is definitely no vulnerability in the very short code snippet you posted, but I don't know what `$u` contains and how it was retrieved.

Comment: `$u = $row["username"]; `  so in my case it redirect to www.mysite.com/username which is in the htaccess 'mod_rewrite' thanks a lot i will accept your  answer :)